# pushl to stack with respect to %ebp leads to segfault

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to print values stored in stack using the variable iIndex, which means number of elements stored in the stack. All values stored in stack are integers, and iIndex has value -4, -8, -12... so on depending on number of elements. However, I get segfault at pushl iIndex(%ebp) on the first loop and I have no clue why this occurs. (iIndex is stored in bss section as 4 bytes)

```
if_f:
    cmpl    $0, iIndex
    je  error1
    movl    iIndex, %ecx    
f_loop:
    pushl   iIndex(%ebp)
    pushl   $resultFormat
    call    printf
    addl    $8, %esp
    addl    $4, iIndex
    cmpl    $0, iIndex
    je  f_loopend
    jmp f_loop
f_loopend:          #need to restore iIndex
    movl    %ecx, iIndex
    jmp input
```

for example, I store value 1 and 2 consecutively in stack, and using GDB, it shows iIndex is -8.

```
f_loop () at sand.s:201
201     pushl   iIndex(%ebp)
(gdb) x/d &iIndex
0x5655701d: -8
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
f_loop () at sand.s:201

eax            0x0  0
ecx            0xfffffff8   -8
edx            0x66 102
ebx            0x0  0
esp            0xffffd1c0   0xffffd1c0
ebp            0xffffd1c8   0xffffd1c8
esi            0xf7fb5000   -134524928
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x56555858   0x56555858 <f_loop>
eflags         0x10282  [ SF IF RF ]
cs             0x23 35
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x2b 43
es             0x2b 43
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x63 99
```

I'd be thankful for any help!

Comment: The effective address specified by  `iIndex(%ebp)` will not be `ebp-8`, it will be `ebp` + the address of `iIndex`. If you wanted the former you need to have the index in a register instead, and then you could write e.g. `pushl (%ebp,%ecx)`

Comment: Keep your local variables in registers, that's what registers are for.

Comment: @Peter Cordes the values in general purpose register changes after calling printf, except for %ebx

Comment: EBX, ESI, EDI, and EBP are all call-preserved (along with ESP of course), in the i386 System V calling convention.  [What are callee and caller saved registers?](//stackoverflow.com/a/56178078) Save/restore one of those around your function and use it.  (You can have it hold a pointer, instead of an index, if you want.)